# How to find out intersections of two absolute value functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

If we are asked to find out common points where two equations intersect each other, for example let us assume that two equations are $Y=12-x^2$ and $Y=4x$, we can solve it in the following way:

\begin{align*}4x&= 12-x^2\\
x^2+4x-12&=0\\
x^2+6x-2x-12&=0\\
x(x+6)-2(x+12)&=0\\
(x-2)(x+6)&=0
\end{align*}

So we have now two roots of $x$, $2$ and $-6$.

Plugging these values in one of the above equations we get two values for $y$, $8$ and $-24$.

So in $(2,8)$ and $(-6,-24)$ the above two lines intersect each other.

But what will we do if we are asked to find out the points where another two equations, $y=|x|$ and $y=|x^2-4|$ meet?

Is there any methodical approach which help find out the common points?

Comment: Yes, there are two possibilities for each equation, so $4$ possibilities in all.  Try them all.

Answer (score 2):

In general, to find intersection between two curves $ y = f(x) $ and $ y = g(x) $,
you would look for solutions of $ f(x) = g(x) $ as you showed in your example.
To find the intersections between $ y = |f(x)| $ and $ y = |g(x)| $, you should thus solve $ |f(x)| = |g(x)| $, or equivalently, $ f^2(x) = g^2(x) $.

With $ f(x) = x $ and $ g(x) = x^2 - 4 $, look for solutions of
$ x^2 = (x^2 - 4)^2$, i.e. the roots of $ x^4 - 9x^2 + 16 $. You should find four of them:

\begin{align}
x_1 &= -\frac{1 + \sqrt{17}}{2} \approx -2.562\\
x_2 &= -\frac{-1 + \sqrt{17}}{2} \approx -1.562\\
x_3 &= \frac{-1 + \sqrt{17}}{2} \approx 1.562\\
x_4 &= \frac{1 + \sqrt{17}}{2} \approx 2.562
\end{align}

Then as you mentioned you can find the intersections by plugging the values into either $ |f(x)| $ or $ |g(x)| $ (it should yield the same results with both).
With your example, the curves therefore intersect at four points:

\begin{align}
P_1 &= (x_1, |f(x_1)|)\\
P_2 &= (x_2, |f(x_2)|)\\
P_3 &= (x_3, |f(x_3)|)\\
P_4 &= (x_4, |f(x_4)|)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to approach it:

We can rewrite the absolute value functions in piecewise notation:

$$y = |x| = \begin{cases} -x, & x\le 0\\
x, &x>0
\end{cases}$$

and
$$y = |x^2 - 4| = |(x-2)(x+2)| = \begin{cases} x^2 - 4, &x\in (-\infty,-2)\cup(2,\infty)\\4 - x^2, &x\in [-2,2]
\end{cases}.$$

So, looking at overlapping domains, you need to find:

1. Intersection points of $y = -x$ and $y = x^2 - 4$ for $x \le -2$.
2. Intersection points of $y = -x$ and $y = 4-x^2$ for $x \in (-2,0)$.
3. Intersection points for $y = x$ and $y = 4-x^2$ for $x\in [0,2)$.
4. Intersection points for $y = x$ and $y = x^2 - 4$ for $x \ge 2$.